# Aggregate filegroups in subpackages into a large filegroup in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I have a parent directory `foo`, and child directories `bar`, `baz`, and `qux`. All four directories contain a bazel BUILD file and define `filegroup` rules that contain all files in the subdirectory (plus various other rules). The problem with this is that the `filegroup` in the parent directory `foo` cannot use a glob to ensure that all files are included (because globs do not cross package boundaries). Instead, I'm currently manually listing all of the children's rules as `srcs` in `foo`, and this manual listing is error-prone because when another child of `foo` is added, the author must remember to add it to the `srcs` of `foo`. I tried to make some progress solving this problem by looking at adding a `genquery` rule in `foo` (thinking I could somehow extract a list of srcs from this programmatically at build time), but recursive patterns are not allowed in the `expression` of a `genquery` rule, so this was unsuccessful.

What is the least mistake-prone way of creating such a filegroup? Is there anything better than my current manual construction of it by listing `srcs`?

Comment: How do you know which subgroups should be in the supergroup?

Answer (score 9):

The `src` of a filegroup is a [list of labels](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#filegroup.srcs).

Hence, you can (and should) do

```
filegroup(
  name = "foo_supergroup",
  srcs = [
     "//foo/bar:smallergroup",
     "//foo/baz:smallergroup",
     "//foo/qux:smallergroup",
  ],
)
```

**Edit**: You can then add a presubmit check that these dependencies are the same as the subgroups.

For, this purpose, I suggest you introduce a tag "yeah":
`foo/BUILD` contains

```
filegroup(
  name = "smallergroup",
  srcs = glob(["*.txt"]),
  tags = ["yeah"],
)
```

Thanks to this:

```
blaze query 'attr("tags", ".*yeah.*", deps(//foo/...))'
//foo/bar:smallergroup
//foo/baz:smallergroup
//foo/qux:smallergroup
```

It then becomes easy to compare with the sources of the supergroup:

```
blaze query 'deps(//foo:foo_supergroup, 1)'
//foo:foo_supergroup
//foo/bar:smallergroup
//foo/baz:smallergroup
//foo/qux:smallergroup
```

In fact, you don't need a specific presubmit. You can use a [`sh_test`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/shell.html#sh_test) (using command `diff`) to compare the output of this two blaze queries made with [`gen_query`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genquery)

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid, because it is error-prone. Many other devs can add subdirectories, and they may occasionally forget to add the smaller group to the supergroup.

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought you were exporting the files and doing a big filegroup again. Let me think about something, but I don't know if your feature request has an answer.

Comment: I suggest you use a presubmit script with a tag to find the expected targets. See updated answer.